# Parse - Query a value in a pointer in an array

Tags: ios, mongodb, parse-server

If I have pointers to multiple `_User` objects in an array, can i query for a value of a `User`.

Ex.
I have a class `Groups` with an array `members`. 
`members = [user1, user2, user3]`.
Can I do something like:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Groups"];
[query whereKey:@"members.name" isEqual:@"James"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a nested query.  Create an "innerQuery" to find Users matching the criteria.  Then constrain a `Group` query with `whereKey:matchesQuery:`.

```
PFQuery *innerQuery = [PFUser query];
// note that referring to the "name" field only makes sense if you've
// added a name field to User (you might mean username here)...
[innerQuery whereKey:@"name" isEqual:@"James"];

// now the main query is setup to match the innerQuery
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Groups"];
[query whereKey:@"members" matchesQuery:innerQuery];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out (probably in a week) and accept if it works

Comment: This still works if the ‘members’ column is an array? I thought an inner query, matchesQuery: , only works if it’s a single pointer object (a single _User object, not an array)?

Comment: @Peter - yes, matchesQuery is like equalTo for the object found by the inner query, and equalTo: when applied to an array is overloaded by parse to mean "contains".